# Exception is lost while consuming a PLINQ query

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, exception, plinq

I observed a weird behavior while experimenting with a PLINQ query. Here is the scenario:

- There is a source `IEnumerable<int>` sequence that contains the two items 1 and 2.
- A Parallel LINQ [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.select) operation is applied on this sequence, projecting each item to itself (`x => x`).
- The resulting `ParallelQuery<int>` query is consumed immediately with a `foreach` loop.
- The `selector` lambda of the `Select` projects successfully the item 1.
- The consuming `foreach` loop throws an exception for the item 1.
- The `selector` lambda throws an exception for the item 2, after a small delay.

What happens next is that the consuming exception is lost! Apparently it is shadowed by the exception thrown afterwards in the `Select`. Here is a minimal demonstration of this behavior:

```
ParallelQuery<int> query = Enumerable.Range(1, 2)
    .AsParallel()
    .Select(x =>
    {
        if (x == 2) { Thread.Sleep(500); throw new Exception($"Oops!"); }
        return x;
    });

try
{
    foreach (int item in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Consuming item #{item} started");
        throw new Exception($"Consuming item #{item} failed");
    }
}
catch (AggregateException aex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"AggregateException ({aex.InnerExceptions.Count})");
    foreach (Exception ex in aex.InnerExceptions)
        Console.WriteLine($"- {ex.GetType().Name}: {ex.Message}");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{ex.GetType().Name}: {ex.Message}");
}
```

Output:

```
Consuming item #1 started
AggregateException (1)
- Exception: Oops!
```

[Live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ggamsF).

Chronologically the consuming exception happens first, and the PLINQ exception happens later. So my understanding is that the consuming exception is more important, and it should be propagated with priority. Nevertheless the only exception that is surfaced is the one that occurs inside the PLINQ code.

**My question is:** why is the consuming exception lost, and is there any way that I can fix the query so that the consuming exception is propagated with priority?

The desirable output is this:

```
Consuming item #1 started
Exception: Consuming item #1 failed
```

Comment: Theoretically, PLINQ could execute many loops before returning a single item, and I don't think there is any documentation stating when an exception will be thrown (ie if item #3 throws then the `foreach` could throw even on the very first execution).

Comment: @Charlieface in the question's example the value 1 is emitted immediately by the PLINQ query, before completing the `selector` of the item 2. I could have configured the query with [`WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.withmergeoptions) to make this behavior even more likely, but apparently it is not required in this case.

Comment: Actually your problem is your thinking execution of the parallel query has anything to do with the order of the `foreach`. If you add a write for `x` in the `Select`, you will see that the parallel query is completely evaluated before the first consuming occurs - sometimes in the order 2, 1. `NotBuffered` makes this obvious, but the default `AutoBuffered` can cause the order to swap all around and you might Select 2,3,1 then consume 3 first... there is no order guarantee once you use `AsParallel`.

Comment: @NetMage my expectation is that the items are emitted by the PLINQ query in (roughly) the same order that the associated `selector`s are completing execution, unless I have requested ordered emission with the [`AsOrdered`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asordered) operator. But my question is not based on this expectation. In the demo the item 1 has been emitted, the consuming `foreach` code failed with an exception, and this exception has been lost. That's the weird thing. Don't you agree that the exception should be surfaced?

Comment: I think what you are seeing is the result of the compiler translation of the `foreach` into a `while (MoveNext())` with a `try` / `finally` to dispose of the enumerator. When the inner exception is thrown, it is caught by the `finally` and the `Dispose` of the enumerator causes all the `Select` threads to finish, which causes an exception inside the `finally` block, which throws away the initial exception as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2911229/2557128). You need to use your own loop and a `CancellationTokenSource` if you want to prevent this.

Comment: @NetMage that's the kind of explanation and solution that I am looking for! Could you show an example of the `CancellationTokenSource`-based solution? Currently I am not able to visualize it.

Comment: See also [PLINQ Exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq#exceptions) where it explains that some items may be processed after an exception is thrown, and [Exceptions in Parallel Loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-handle-exceptions-in-parallel-loops): "an unhandled exception causes the loop to terminate as soon as all currently running iterations finish"

Comment: @NetMage from a quick look, the two links [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq#exceptions), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-handle-exceptions-in-parallel-loops) don't seem to be helpful for explaining or solving this question's problem. I am not expecting that the `ParallelQuery<int>` will complete immediately after an exception happens in the parallel `Select`. But I do expect that an exception thrown in the consuming `foreach` will not be lost!

Comment: The links explain how an exception in a parallel query consumption might not stop all processing of the parallel query. The link in my first comment about the `finally` block explains how an exception during `finally` processing will throw away the first exception.

Comment: @NetMage you mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911215/what-happens-if-a-finally-block-throws-an-exception/2911229#2911229) link? Yea, this gives useful information about the behavior of the `finally` in general. But there is no hint in the other two links that the PLINQ propagates exceptions via the `Dispose` route, that can cause consuming exceptions to be lost. Not even the smartest person that ever lived (Archimedes!) could deduct this behavior by just reading these two documentation pages, I think.

Comment: Not necessarily the smartest person, but I read a lot of C# internals stuff (programming languages and their implementations being both a hobby and something I studied/worked with in college) and immediately thought that the compiler implementation of the `foreach` would yield an explanation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are seeing is the result of the compiler translation of the `foreach` into a `while (MoveNext())` with a `try`/`finally` to dispose of the enumerator. When the inner exception is thrown, it is caught by the finally and the `Dispose()` of the enumerator causes all the `Select` threads to finish, which causes an exception inside the `finally` block, which throws away the initial exception as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2911229/2557128). You need to use your own loop and a `try`/`catch` if you want to prevent this, though I think the Microsoft recommendation would be to use a `try`/`catch` in the `Select` to be closer to the source of the exception.

Here is a modification of your existing code replacing the `foreach` with the compiler generated expansion of `foreach` using an enumerator. (I use LINQPad to see the C# 1.0 equivalent code / IL code from the compiler.)

You can capture any exceptions during the `Dispose` of the enumerator and then bundle them up with the original exception into an `AggregateException` when you catch them.

I wrapped the boilerplate into an extension method to replace the normal `foreach`:

```
var b = true;
var query = Enumerable.Range(1, 3)
    .AsParallel()
    .Select(x => {
        Thread.Sleep(50 * (x - 1));
        Console.WriteLine($"Select({x})");
        if (x >= 2) {
            throw new Exception($"Oops {x}!");
        }
        return x;
    });

try {
    query.ForEachAggregatingExceptions(item => {
        Console.WriteLine($"Consuming item #{item} started");
        if (b) {
            throw new Exception($"Consuming item #{item} failed");
        }
    });
}
catch (AggregateException aex) {
    Console.WriteLine($"AggregateException ({aex.InnerExceptions.Count})");
    foreach (Exception ex in aex.InnerExceptions)
        Console.WriteLine($"- {ex.GetType().Name}: {ex.Message}");
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{ex.GetType().Name}: {ex.Message}");
}

public static class ParallelQueryExt {
    public static void ForEachAggregatingExceptions<T>(this ParallelQuery<T> pq, Action<T> processFn) {
        Exception FirstException = null;
        var e = pq.GetEnumerator();
        try {
            while (e.MoveNext())
                processFn(e.Current);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            FirstException = ex;
        }
        finally {
            if (e != null) {
                try {
                    e.Dispose();
                }
                catch (AggregateException aex) { // combine exceptions from Dispose with FirstException if any
                    if (FirstException != null) {
                        throw new AggregateException(aex.InnerExceptions.Prepend(FirstException));
                    }
                    else
                        throw;
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { // combine single exception from Dispose with FirstException if any
                    throw new AggregateException(new[] { ex, FirstException });
                }
                if (FirstException != null) // re-throw FirstException if no others occurred
                    throw FirstException;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS The `b` variable and the `if` prevents the compiler from optimizing out the `while` loop into an `if` since it can figure out the `throw` will prevent the loop from executing more than once pass.

Comment: Thanks NetMage for the answer! This seems to solve the problem, albeit with lots of boilerplate code in the consuming site. But I am not sure that I understand the need for the `CancellationTokenSource`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias The `CancellationTokenSource` is an option if you uncomment out the `cts.Cancel()` and instead comment out the `try {` `} catch { }` lines around the `e.Dispose()`. Then the threads will be cancelled, and the exception in the `Select` won't get thrown. But sometimes it might be, depending on who wins the race, so I prefer the `try`/`catch` instead.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I modified my answer to bundle up any exceptions that happen during the `Dispose` and return them all if necessary. Note that since this is parallel multi-threaded code, not all exceptions that would occur if every `Select` ran to completion will necessarily occur since they may be at different points during execution, or not yet scheduled to execute at all.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you want to do with the `CancellationTokenSource`. You want to prevent PLINQ's worker threads from starting more work after the failure of the consuming `foreach`. I would guess that the PLINQ knows how to do it by itself. Calling `Dispose` should have the same effect as cancelling the cancellation token.

Comment: Btw your idea about combining the caught `FirstException` with the `e.Dispose()` exception is pretty good! But it might be better if the propagated exception is always an `AggregateException`, in order to simplify the outermost handling code that logs the errors in the console.

Comment: You could consider including [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74623812/exception-is-lost-while-consuming-a-plinq-query/74635235?noredirect=1#comment131739551_74623812) inside the answer, so that it answers also the "why" part of the question. Currently it answers only the "how to fix" part!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Good suggestion. I also wrapped the boiler plate into an extension method which made me realize Microsoft would probably suggest putting the `try` in the `Select` body and using a regular `foreach`, but that has its down sides as well.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Also, when I tested with the `CancellationTokenSource`, it definitely prevented the `Dispose` from throwing. `Dispose` waits for the currently running threads to finish instead of immediately cancelling them (I saw that documented but I lost the reference), which means your `throw` for 2 get executed during the `Dispose` but not when cancelled, assuming it is still in the `Sleep`, hence my conclusion that it is too risky to count on, as it sets up a race condition.

Comment: Now it's much better! Btw I doubt that canceling the `CancellationTokenSource` has the effect of aborting or [interrupting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.interrupt) `ThreadPool` threads. I might have to experiment with it, and see if I can reproduce the effect of preventing the `Dispose` from throwing.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias You may be right, further testing seems to indicate I may have had the `throw` in the `Select` commented out when testing the cancellation token. I took out the suggestion that a `CancellationTokenSource` might help :)

Answer (score 1):

[NetMage's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74623812/exception-is-lost-while-consuming-a-plinq-query/74635235#74635235) explains that the observed behavior is caused by the error thrown on `Dispose` of the PLINQ enumerator. My guess about why the PLINQ library violates the [common wisdom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577607/should-you-implement-idisposable-dispose-so-that-it-never-throws/) about throwing exceptions on `Dispose`, which is to avoid throwing unless the error is critical, is because the library was introduced on .NET 4.0. In this .NET version an unobserved faulted `Task` resulted in the termination of the processes. The process was crashing when the faulted `Task` was garbage collected, after raising the [`TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception). So the PLINQ designers had to choose between throwing on `Dispose`, swallowing the exception completely, or crashing the process, and they choose what seemed like the lesser evil of the available options. That's my guess.

Had the library been authored on .NET 4.5, they might had decided differently. In that .NET version, the process would no longer crash when an unobserved faulted `Task` was garbage collected. Reverting to the .NET 4.0 policy is still possible through a [configuration setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/throwunobservedtaskexceptions-element), but I doubt that anyone ever used this setting to revert to the original irrational behavior.

My approach for fixing PLINQ's error-losing behavior is a bit different that NetMage's approach. Instead of bundling all errors in an `AggregateException`, I prefer to suppress the exception that is thrown by PLINQ on `Dispose`, and propagate it through the `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` mechanism. This can be achieved easily by just creating a faulted task with the [`Task.FromException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromexception) method, and leaving it unobserved:

```
/// <summary>
/// Suppresses the error that might be thrown by the enumerator on Dispose.
/// The error triggers the TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException event.
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<TSource> SuppressDisposeException<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    try
    {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext()) yield return enumerator.Current;
        try { enumerator.Dispose(); } finally { enumerator = null; }
    }
    finally
    {
        try { enumerator?.Dispose(); }
        catch (Exception ex) { _ = Task.FromException(ex); }
    }
}
```

The `finally` block of the iterator can be invoked either by the `MoveNext` or the `Dispose` of the autogenerated enumerator. In case it is invoked on `MoveNext`, we want to propagated normally a source `Dispose` exception. We only want to suppress it if it happens on the autogenerated `Dispose`. That's the reason for disposing the source enumerator preferentially in the `try` block, and only as a fallback in the `finally` block.

Usage example:

```
IEnumerable<int> query = Enumerable.Range(1, 2)
    .AsParallel()
    .Select(x => /* ... */ x)
    .SuppressDisposeException();
```

In order to watch the `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` event being triggered, you might have to call [`GC.Collect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect) as part of the test.

The justification for suppressing the exception on `Dispose` from the synchronous execution flow, is because I consider the parallel nature of PLINQ as a form of speculative execution. The PLINQ engine might do more work than what the consumer of the query is interested to receive. So in case the consumer abandons the enumeration prematurely, either voluntarily by `break`ing the `foreach` loop, or unwillingly because it suffered an exception, the PLINQ should not bother the consumer with anything that might happen past the point that the consumer lost interest for the enumeration.